# How to get multiple widows to appear in a slightly different position?

Tags: python, window, tkinter

I have this program that stores some information about my books, and this information is shown in windows, that appear whenever I double-click a book title in a list. But there is the possibility of searching for a book using it's title or author, and that can make the program open multiple windows. My problem is, all the windows are opened one over the other, and, until the I move a window, or close it, it seems that only one window was opened. Is it possible to, with python and tkinter, make the windows appear in slightly different positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` method of a window to specify where you want it to appear. For example, `w.geometry("+100+200")` will open the window `w` at coordinate 100,200. Each time you open a new window, adjust the coordinates appropriately.

Normally, though, this is something the window manager does for you. It's odd that it's not doing this for you.

The `geometry` method is documented here, among other places: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method

Comment: Well, for that I would have to set a counter right? But then would it be possible to make the counter reset everytime the `Toplevel()` windows are closed? (I am already using the `.geometry` method.)   Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you're already using the `geometry` method, maybe you're accidentally setting the x/y coordinate to the same value every time. Try removing the use of `geometry` altogether and see if the window manager starts managing the location for you.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was using it to make the windows appear on the center of the screen. Thanks again.